# Is there a symbol for potential equality?

Tags: notation

Is there a symbol for potential equality? Essentially I'd like to condense:

$$
(a = b) \lor (a \ne b)
$$

so that I can express the phrase "a may or may not be equal to b". Apologies if my syntax is not entirely correct; I come from a computer science background.

Comment: What context would you want to do this in? I would personally use an equals sign with a question mark above it.

Comment: That's what I've usually seen as well - what Tom suggested.

Comment: What would you like a symbol that carries no information? Or if it should, what kind of information you would like it to have?

Comment: From a logical point of view, $(a=b)\lor (a\ne b)$ is a tautology. One can condense it by saying nothing.

Comment: True, but I had a case in which I specifically wanted to emphasize that fact by asking whether it was the case that (a = b) or the case that (a ?= b)... unless there is a way to condense THAT?

Comment: André, in cases where it might potentially be assumed that $a = b$ or assumed that $a \ne b$ you may want to be explicit in saying that it's not known. Usually the way I phrase the meaning of this needed symbol is "does not necessarily equal." Let's say you're trying to prove the general case for a theorem and find that the theorem is false, even though it works in some specific cases. It helps to be able to make the distinction.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to state that $a$ and $b$ are of the same type, so that it makes sense to ask whether they are equal in the first place?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most common usage I have seen is

$$a \overset{?}{=} b$$

Usually its context I've seen is before you're trying to prove that they indeed equal or something of that matter.

Comment: No Unicode symbol for a question mark over an equals sign?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You can define it as a new command if you're going to be using it a lot. Also, \overset allows for other symbols to be used above an equals sign, such as !. \overset and amsmath are preferred over \stackrel{?}{=} I believe.

Comment: I don't see it often in texts - usually it is not needed, as noted in the comments to the OP's question. I'd definitely say it's more informal. I've seen it in lectures given by my professors, as well as in a few texts - but nothing 'well known' like Rudin, Spivak, or something like that.

Comment: @JakePetroules There actually is a Unicode symbol, called Questioned Equal To: ≟

Comment: ≟ is the unicode symbol. Unicode: U+225F, UTF-8: E2 89 9F

Answer (score 12):

## ≟

The Unicode symbol ≟ can be used for questionable equality.

Unicode Reference: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+225F